# Why do I only get ESLint warnings during CRA build and not when running Eslint on the CLI?

Tags: create-react-app, lint

I just inherited a Create React App based project and noticed something peculiar. When I run `npx eslint src/` there are no issues. No output, nothing. Even introducing some errors seemed to make no difference! On the other hand, when doing `npm start` I can see lots of ESLint output in the console:

```
Compiled with warnings.

./src/Components/Exercises/Edit.tsx
  Line 100:9:  'generateSubtypesList' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

./src/Components/Workouts/Table.tsx
  Line 1280:45:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 1281:43:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq

./src/Components/Workouts/Edit.tsx
  Line 12:3:   'TextField' is defined but never used                                                                                     @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  Line 381:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'delSuperSetList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/Components/Sessions/Edit.tsx
  Line 130:6:  React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'delSuperSetList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/Components/Workouts/Add.tsx
  Line 13:3:   'TextField' is defined but never used                                                                                       @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  Line 176:6:  React Hook React.useCallback has a missing dependency: 'delSuperSetList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/Components/Workouts/ExerciseSetsList.tsx
  Line 145:34:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 150:30:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
  Line 150:58:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq

./src/Components/Settings/Availability.tsx
  Line 177:23:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
...
```

What is happening here and how can I make ESLint output these warnings on the command line?

## Manually adding ESLint v7 makes things work as expected?

So the strange thing I found is that if I do `npm install eslint` so that version 7 gets installed, everything works as expected:

```
$ node ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js  --version
v6.8.0

$ node ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js  src/

$ # nothing was found

$ node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js  --version
v7.32.0

$ node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js  src

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Clients/Details.tsx
  41:10  warning  'isPropertyDeclaration' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Exercises/Add.tsx
   72:9  warning  'generateCategoryList' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  168:9  warning  'validateInput' is assigned a value but never used         @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Exercises/Details.tsx
  8:10  warning  'ExerciseTypes' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  9:8   warning  'CloseIcon' is defined but never used      @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Exercises/Edit.tsx
  95:9  warning  'generateSubtypesList' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Exercises/Listings.tsx
  333:56  warning  'is_user_exercise' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Menus/SubMenu.tsx
  1:8   warning  'React' is defined but never used    @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  2:10  warning  'NavLink' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Schedules/Details.tsx
   3:10  warning  'format' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  14:3   warning  'Info' is defined but never used    @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Sessions/Cancel.tsx
  63:9  warning  'generateTimeToSession' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/Users/my-user/dev/myproj-trainer-web/src/Components/Sessions/Details.tsx
  504:18  warning  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
```

I don't really understand why version 6.8 keeps silent on the CLI, but not when interfacing with the CRA build?

Comment: Experiencing a similar issue, except that I'm using `v8.4.0` of `eslint` and not getting certain rules.  Wondering if maybe CRA is using some different lint config rules?